# How do I use $expand on ownerid to fetch SystemUser properties with the Dynamics 365 Web API?

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm

I'm using Postman to query the Dynamics 365 Web API to fetch Account records. I'm trying to use `expand` to fetch some properties from the related SystemUser record via the `ownerid` field.

Here is what I think the query should look like:

```
https://myorg.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/accounts?$select=name&$expand=ownerid($select=fullname)
```

When I submit this query I get the error:

> Could not find a property named 'fullname' on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.principal

I *know* that the `fullname` property definitely exists on a SystemUser.

If I remove the `($select=fullname)` part of the query I get the following JSON result but I was expect lots of properties for the expanded owner.

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://myorg.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#accounts(name,ownerid)",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"1564360\"",
      "name": "My Account",
      "accountid": "82b287d6-0dc7-e811-a95e-000d3ab1ab19",
      "ownerid": {
        "ownerid": "5f8872b1-0189-e811-a975-000d3ab38ab1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I change the `expand` to use `primarycontactid` then this works and I can fetch fields from a Contact record.

I've checked the documentation and I'm no further forward.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/query-data-web-api

**How do I use expand to fetch properties from a SystemUser record via the ownerid property of Accounts?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select Dynamics CRM reference attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53080848/how-do-i-select-dynamics-crm-reference-attributes)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the issue is due to the Owner field being able to point at either a SystemUser or Team record.

If I expand with `owninguser` then I can fetch the correct properties from the related Systemuser.

Answer (score 1):

```
/api/data/v9.2/new_customs?$select=createdon,_ownerid_value&$expand=owninguser($select=fullname)&$filter=(owninguser/systemuserid%20ne%20null)&$top=50
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply

Comment: @DenFav: That response doesn't make much since here, since this is asking about a URI format. This isn't a literal link to another resource, but a pattern that the OP can use.